# Extracting two columns from a dataframe contained within a nested list

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, nested-lists

I've pulled data from an API and converted it from JSON and have ended up with a dataframe ("Participants") of information on tournaments from a game that contains an identifier number ('id') identifying the participant in a tournament and then a deeply nested list containing information on the game the participant played. Within that nested list is a dataframe containing columns I'm interested in extracting. This is an image of the relevant columns from my dataframe.

[Image of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsxXs.png)

And these are the top two items in the list for example.

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$description
[1] ""

[[1]]$faction
[1] "galacticempire"

[[1]]$name
[1] "Unnamed Squadron"

[[1]]$pilots
          id       name points           ship upgrades.force-power   upgrades.sensor upgrades.modification upgrades.talent upgrades.gunner
1 darthvader darthvader     84  tieadvancedx1                 hate firecontrolsystem          afterburners            NULL            NULL
2 soontirfel soontirfel     54 tieinterceptor                 NULL              NULL                  NULL        predator            NULL
3 puresabacc puresabacc     62   tieskstriker                 NULL              NULL                  NULL     outmaneuver    fifthbrother

[[1]]$points
[1] 200

[[1]]$vendor
[[1]]$vendor$yasb
[[1]]$vendor$yasb$builder
[1] "Yet Another Squad Builder 2.0"

[[1]]$vendor$yasb$builder_url
[1] "https://raithos.github.io/"

[[1]]$vendor$yasb$link
[1] "https://raithos.github.io/?f=Galactic%20Empire&d=v5!s!173:204,113,-1,105:;179:127,-1,-1:;210:126,82,-1,-1:&sn=Unnamed%20Squadron&obs="



[[1]]$version
[1] "2.0.0"


[[2]]
[[2]]$name
[1] "Adam"

[[2]]$faction
[1] "scumandvillainy"

[[2]]$favourite
[1] TRUE

[[2]]$pilots
            ship upgrades.talent upgrades.crew upgrades.sensor upgrades.title        id points
1    fangfighter        fearless          NULL            NULL           NULL   fennrau     71
2    fangfighter        fearless          NULL            NULL           NULL oldteroch     59
3 g1astarfighter       trickshot           000 advancedsensors     misthunter      4lom     63

[[2]]$format
[1] "Extended"

[[2]]$version
[1] "2.3.5"

[[2]]$points
[1] 193
```

For each item in this list, I'm interested in extracting the 'id' column and the 'ship' column from the $pilots item in the list, appending the 'id' from my intial dataframe to these columns, and binding it into a new dataframe. I'd then do some additional manipulation on this dataframe.

I have figured out how to extract other items from my list. For example, I know that the code below extracts the 'points' item for each item in the list of lists.

```
lapply(participants$lists, "[[", 'points')
```

I also know that the following code would extract the 'id' column from the 'pilots' dataframe in the first item of the list.

```
lists[[1]][['pilots']]['id']
```

However, I'm not sure how to implement that subsetting as a function over the entire list, and I'm not sure how to also append the identifier from the "Participants" dataframe to those items.

Pulling out the entire 'pilots' dataframe from each item in the list and binding it together doesn't work because the dataframes have differing numbers of columns. I've also tried flattening the list, but this hasn't seemed to get me where I want to go, but maybe I've just done it incorrectly.

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(participants$lists, "[[", 'pilots'))
```

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We extract the "pilots' element from the `list` and subset by selecting the 'id', 'ship' columns

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(participants$lists, function(x) x$pilots[c("id", "ship")]))
```

---

If there are elements in the 'pilots' that doesn't have both columns, and want to remove those elements, then using an `if` condition, we can do

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(participants$lists, function(x) {
              x1 <- x$pilots
              if(all(c("id", "ship") %in% names(x1))) {
                x1[c("id", "ship")]
               }
             }))
```

If we want to add the 'id' from `participants`

```
lst1 <- lapply(participants$lists, function(x) {
              x1 <- x$pilots
              if(all(c("id", "ship") %in% names(x1))) {
                x1[c("id", "ship")]
               }
             })
i1 <- sapply(lst1, NROW) > 0
lst1[i1] <- Map(cbind, id2 = participants$id[i1], lst1[i1])
out <- do.call(rbind, lst1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That gives me the following error:

 Error in `[.data.frame`(x$pilots, c("id", "ship")) : 
  undefined columns selected 

This is the traceback:
6.
stop("undefined columns selected") 
5.
`[.data.frame`(x$pilots, c("id", "ship")) 
4.
x$pilots[c("id", "ship")] 
3.
FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2.
lapply(participants$lists, function(x) x$pilots[c("id", "ship")]) 
1.
do.call(rbind, lapply(participants$lists, function(x) x$pilots[c("id", 
    "ship")]

Comment: @sethltaylor Do you have both the 'id', 'ship' in all the elements of 'pilots'. i.e. is there a chance that some data.frame doesn't have the column?

Comment: If I flatten the list once using flatten() (calling it 'lists_flat') then lists_flat$pilots[c('id', 'ship') gives me the columns I want from the first 'pilots' dataframe, but lapply(lists_flat, function(x) x$pilots[c('id', 'ship')]) gives me "Error in x$pilots : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"

Comment: @sethltaylor Can you try `do.call(rbind, lapply(do.call(c, lapply(participants$lists, function(x) x$pilots)), subset, select = c("id", "ship")))`

Comment: Yes it must be the case that one of the dataframes doesn't have that column. I subsetted my list to 5 elements that I could verify had it and your solution worked perfectly. Is there a way to drop the dataframes from the list that don't have those columns? And do you have any advice on how to append my participant id from the overall dataframe to the correct rows in new dataframe of pilots and ships?

Comment: That function gives me the error "Error in subset.default(X[[i]], ...) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default". Though it still must be the missing columns issue since your prior solution works for that test list of 5 items.

Comment: @sethltaylor So, I guess my initial code was correct except that it is the issue I mentioned earlier about some elements  doesn't have the 'id' or 'ship'

Comment: The new code works perfectly. Is there any way to append the participant id column from the initial data frame (participants$id) to the rows of this new data frame? So if the participant with id 100 has 'ship 1', 'ship 2', 'ship 3' in the original list the new dataframe would append id 100 to the rows containing those ships from his game.

Comment: @sethltaylor Can you show the output currently with the updated code and what you expect.  It is not clear to me.  Here, we have two columns 'id' and 'ship'

Comment: [Example Dataframe](https://imgur.com/wPQjKNA)

The above link is an example of the output of your code and the third column I'm trying to add. For example, the first three ships in the list are associated with participant$id == 5125, the next 3 are associated with 5126, the next three 5124, then the next four 5118 (so the number can vary). Is there any way to programmatically add the participant$id from the match to the appropriate ships in the new dataframe?

Comment: That seems to throw an error at this point:

i1 <- sapply(lst1, nrow) > 0
Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: @sethltaylor just change it to `i1 <- sapply(lst1, NROW) > 0`